# DataTable Table CSS Blank Space Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using DataTable in my project and i have a strange issue. [Click to see my DataTable example](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)

I attached a picture which is about my problem.

How can i remove the blank space with filter buttons and column headers?

[image: Blank space]

It looks like when i use Google Chrome Web Inspector.

[image: Chrome View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override the margin.top property like that:

```
#example.dataTable {
    margin-top: 0px!important;
}
```

Note: If you prepare a JSfiddle we can see the code and fix it for you...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i tried it but i failed. i gonna prepare a JSfiddle tomorrow.

Comment: it works now! thank you! 

#example.dataTable {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    .dataTable {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    #example.dataTable {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    #example.display.dataTable {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }